# How to connect a client with other one in a namespace socket.io?

Tags: socket.io

```
dbOperations.saveRequest(db, requestId, requestTime, location, eventData.citizenId, 'waiting', function(results) {

        //2. AFTER saving, fetch nearby cops from citizen’s location
        dbOperations.fetchNearestCops(db, location.coordinates, function(results) {
            eventData.requestId = requestId;
            //3. After fetching nearest cops, fire a 'request-for-help' event to each of them
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                io.sockets.in(results[i].userId).emit('request-for-help', eventData);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

i wanna  send event to a particular cop but not all .........
and i don't exactly get how does io.socket.in work could any one suggest me aproper reference to proceed plzzzzzzz...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what we are doing in our project is that we have created a layer which manages one-to-one mapping between userId and socketId. Thus whenever user socket is connected we first register that user thus this layer add mapping of userId to socketId and when user disconnect we remove mapping on the basis of socketId.

Thus if you want to send to a user, pass this userId to this layer and this layer if have mapping to socketId will send data.

**Pseudocode**

```
var userMap ={};
var socketMap ={};

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

   socket.on('register', function(userId, cb) {
      /*Our custom event, which on basis of userId add mapping between user and socketid*/ 
      userMap[userId] = socket.id;          //save user
      socketMap[socket.id] = userId;        //save socket
   });

   socket.on('disconnect', function(userId, cb) {
     /*When socket disconnect, remove mapping*/ 
      delete userMap[socketMap[socket.id]];         //remove user
      delete socketMap[socket.id];                  //remove socket
   });

});

/*Function used to send message*/
function sendMessage(userId){
    if(userMap[userId]){
          io.to(userMap[userId]).emit('message');
    }       
}
```

Comment: than you soo much bro.